# Slow video after sleep on an Lenovo Edge 13

Tags: 11.04, video, intel-graphics, sleep

I have Ubuntu 11.04 on my Lenovo Edge 13 with i3-380UM processor (with integrated graphics). After sleep/hibenate video is really choppy. After reboot all playack is fine. Any ideas? Thank in advance.

Comment: I think it is lack of RAM, or lack of memory in the GPU. because it can't cache the whole playback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution - new drivers from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50554/does-11-04-support-sandy-bridge) answer was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a compiz issue. Try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `compiz --replace`.

Comment: You provide very little information, which makes it difficult to help you.